# Multiple "LIKE" string search on Algolia

Tags: algolia

I'm currently researching on functionalities on Algolia for a location service. I have a simple question.

Is it possible to search with multiple "like" string, something similar to as below in MySQL?

```
select * from route
WHERE pickup LIKE "51%"
AND dropoff LIKE "80%";
```

On Algolia, let's assume there is a simple index consists of small data:

```
[{
  "pickup" : "51105",
  "dopoff" : "80637"
},
{
  "pickup" : "51105",
  "dopoff" : "39871"
},
{
  "pickup" : "32791",
  "dopoff" : "40545"
}]
```

I've checked it can be retrieved by given exactly two params, like:

```
index.search({
  facetFilters: 'pickup: 51105, dropoff:80637',
}
```

Also we can use normal query with typo for one of target params,

```
index.search({
  query: '51',
  restrictSearchableAttributes: [
    'pickup'
  ],
}
```

but neither of them is satisfied with my original requirement.

I've found a post that might be related to my question in algolia community, but It woundn't give me much insights.
[Querying multiple terms in multiple fields](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/querying-multiple-terms-in-multiple-fields/1414)

I'd think there is a solution as I believe this'd be a quite common use-case.
It would be great if anybody has encountered similar situation or some insights. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best equivalent of MySQL `LIKE` queries applied to facets would be to use `searchForFacetValues`.

Here is the documentation about the feature: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/search/#search-for-facet-values